# a point of inflection

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Question, I am  learning how to sketch gradient function using the given features of the function y = f(x). 
The question in the book asked to sketch the gradient function of y=f(x)
[y=f(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL94Q.jpg)

I was able to sketch it  ([y=f'(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzNec.jpg)), but the question got me thinking that if a y=f(x) has a point of inflection at x=a then y=f'(x) has an equal root at x=a since it touches the curve touches y=f'(x) at x=a. I want to know if this statement is true.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Take $f (x)=\sin (x) $.

$x=\pi $ is an inflection point since $f''(\pi)=0$ with change of sign.

but $f'(\pi)\ne 0$.